# BusinessProcessManagement with BonitaSoft Engine

Tags: business-process-management

I am very much new to BPM (Business Process Management), I was asked to go through the Bonitasoft BPM and got an idea of it. I have created a sample Business Process in the Bonita Studio, after that what should I do with this process I created? I mean how will I use this in my application?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll the find the Bonita forum at http://www.bonitasoft.org/forum/

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy the Bonita Web App separately or you can use Bonita Engine APIs in your own Web App to grab required data.